# Angular 2+ create/change CSS class during run time

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a CSS class on run time with `<style>` the problem is that the style element ignores the `*ngIf`
I even tried to put false in the `*ngIf` just to check.

```html
<div *ngIf="  false" >
  <style type="text/css" >

    .brand_currency:before,
    .brand_currency:before {
      content: "\f155";
    }
  </style>
</div>
<div *ngIf=" true">
  <style type="text/css" >
    .brand_currency:before,
    .brand_currency:before {
      content: "\f153";
    }
  </style>
</div>
```

and in the `html` i see

[image]

as you can see this `*ngIf` didn't work, is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Why are you not using `ngStyle`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava i want to create/change a class not change 1 element style

Comment: What exactly is your root problem? I don't know whether it's possible to have a `*ngIf` decorator create a CSS class if necessary but you could declare multiple CSS classes beforehand and change the classes of your HTML elements dynamically depending on variables. Would that offer a same solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using `<style>` inside Angular template let alone combine it with `*ngIf`. You could instead have different CSS selectors and switch between them using [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) binding with ternary operator.

Try the following

CSS

```css
.brand_currency.content1:before {
  content: "\f155";
}

.brand_currency.content2:before {
  content: "\f153";
}
```

Angular template

```html
<div class="brand_currency" [ngClass]="someCondition ? 'content1' : 'content2'"></div>
```

Comment: i have this class in a lot of components that's why i wanted to change the class itself

Comment: So you'd be adding the `*ngIf` blocks to all these components?

Comment: no only on the start component, this way it will effect everything

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code I hope it will solve your problem

```
<div *ngIf="false" >
<style type="text/css" >

 .brand_currency:before,
 .brand_currency:before {
  content: "\f155";
}
</style>
</div>
<div *ngIf="true">
<style type="text/css" >
 .brand_currency:before,
 .brand_currency:before {
   content: "\f153";
}
  </style>
</div>
```

Try this one exactly before adding the style

```
 <div *ngIf="isValid;else other_content">
Your style here
  </div>
 <ng-template #other_content>
 else style
</ng-template>
```

Comment: is it applying both or not